# getting result from PUBLIC.tableName.tableScan insted of index on explain Select * from table

Tags: h2

I'm having a concept table having 60 million records, I've created an index on the columns
the problem is h2 is scanning the table instead of scanning through the index on executing a select query.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM tableName` simply returns all rows from the specified table, the only way to do that is to perform a complete table scan, so this output of `EXPLAIN` is actually expected. With a large table such query can be slow, because it needs to create a complete copy of your table.

If you don't  really need all rows, you can limit the output to the specified size, for example, `SELECT * FROM tableName FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY` will return only 100 rows and will be executed much faster. If you need all of them, but you want to avoid creation of temporary copy of your table, you can add `;LAZY_QUERY_EXECUTION=TRUE` to JDBC URL, with this connection setting H2 will stream the results when possible instead of construction of complete result set before it starts to return any rows.

Indexes are suitable for another purpose. For example, query like `SELECT * from tableName WHERE columnName = 10` will use an index on column `columnName` to read only rows with value `10`. Without such index this query will also perform a slow table scan.

Indexes can also be used to speed up the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks For the explanation, see I want to create the Lucene index of the DB and I am fetching records in a chunk of 100000. example : select tableName.id, tableName.active, tableName.effective-time From Concept Limit 0,100000. The problem is when I'm trying to fetch a record after 4 million, my query takes more than 25 seconds to execute, I want to increase the speed so that the Lucene index can be created faster.

Comment: You need to use the keyset pagination (with an appropriate index) instead of slow (for almost every DBMS) offset pagination.